# FlowLayoutPanel. Custom Scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, scrollbar, flowlayoutpanel

Is it possible to use a third party scroll control inside a FlowLayoutPanel? Thing is that we are using devexpress controls and the FlowLayoutPanel's scrollbar controls does not look good.

Is there a way to custom paint or replace them with devexpress controls.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at the [XtraLayoutControl](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/) Suite that provides a greater functionality in comparison with the FlowLayoutPanel control.  Also, please note that our skinning engine works only with DevExpress controls and thus standard controls and their elements are not skinned.

Finally, this is just an idea, and it might work.  You should turn off the FlowLayoutControl scrollbars and position our scrollbars near the control.  You will have to handle the scrollbars' Scroll event to scroll the FlowLayoutControl programmatically and also synchronize the scrollbars position.  This is not an easy task, but I just have no other idea on how this can be done.

Comment: We did initially went with the XtraLayout. But the drag/drop  operations were hard to control. For eg if we needed to disable the 'Top' drop option. I have posted a question here. http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/98889.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need and came up with a solution combining the standard FlowLayoutPanel with the DevExpress XtraScrollableControl. See my post [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q321707.aspx).

Comment: Yea, I end up using the XtraScrollableControl. But only using flowLayoutPanel anchor to Top and Autoresize = true worked for me. No need for the resize event.

Comment: @Aseem: You're right and even better! I had missed anchoring the FlowLayoutPanel on the right, while also setting AutoSize = true. Thanks for sharing!